# Windows software to create concordances from .pdf and .txt files?

Tags: software

I am new to Stack Exchange, so if this question fits better on another board, please let me know.

I am looking for Windows-compatible software that will create a concordance from .pdf and .txt files. Ideally it would work with languages that have diacritical marks (Spanish, French) in addition to English. Is anyone aware of a program that can do this?

I have searched online already and have so far only been able to find old software whose sites no longer work very well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you ready [to buy the software](http://provalisresearch.com/products/content-analysis-software/)? Will [free software in Russian](http://www.blog-kaplunoff.ru/poleznosti/41-novaya-programma-dlya-kopirajterov-textus-pro.html) do for you?

Comment: There's an online service http://www.wordcounter.com/

Comment: I'd be willing to buy if I didn't have to sell my car to get the software :). I will check out the Russian software. The wordcounter site is useful, and is a good start for what I'd like to do.

Comment: [This one](http://www.hermetic.ch/wfca/wfca.htm) is just $60 for a lifetime license.

Comment: This is a practical question about (corpus) linguistic analysis, which makes it perfectly on topic on SE Linguistics. Also, from a practical point of view, people on Software Recommendations are not particularly likely to be able to provide a good answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probably most widely used concordance software is Laurence Anthony's [AntConc](http://www.laurenceanthony.net/antconc_index.html). It has a range of functions beyond producing concordances, such as determining word counts and collocations. It can also handle regular expressions. AntConc is free and runs on a number of different platforms. I regularly recommend it to students, use it in teaching, and know many colleagues who do. This may be subjective, but I think AntConc is (together with [WordSmith](http://www.lexically.net/wordsmith/), which is not free) widely accepted as a standard tool in corpus linguistics.

AntConc cannot handle pdf files. You can use the [AntFileConverter](http://www.laurenceanthony.net/software.html) (scroll down on the website) to convert your files from pdf to txt. Note that how well this works may vary depending on the pdf files - there might be issues with special characters.

Comment: This is very useful. I'm sorry I'm so tardy in responding!

Comment: AntConc 4 can now handle PDF files and Word files.